# Importing NuGet .dlls from .NET sdk install to Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I've been trying to develop something in an offline environment where it's difficult to get hold of packages for dependencies. Developing in VS2022 in C#, .Net 7.0.

Today I managed to get hold of xunit 2.5 and immediate dependencies to build a unit test suite, but after building an XUnit test project in VS2022 it became apparent that the core microsoft packages were out of date, namely NuGet.Frameworks, and coverlet.collector. I unfortunately can't get hold of these packages from the internet.

I do however have a separate install of dotnet 7.0.something (for cmd line usage) where I can see the prerequisite .dlls of a suitably recent version to install xunit, but it's not part of the VS2022 NuGet.

So, how do I make use of these .dlls within Visual Studio? I'm a bit new to C# and the VS development environment so I'm flummoxed.

I've tried pointing the VS2022 NuGet at the separate dotnet install directory, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your situation like this:

[image]

First of all, Visual Studio must have a source to install the packages.

If on your side there is no remote source, the Visual Studio will use the Offline source:

**`Name: Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`**

**`Default Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\`**

If you go to the path of the offline source and can't find the packages you want, then it is unable to install in the xunit project.

You must prepare it and put it to the offline source path, otherwise, your project will be unable to use the package you want.

Go to the Nuget Gallery which is the official Nuget repository:

[Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/)

search for the package you want in that place, download it, and transfer the package to the offline path by some means:

[image]